# ready made forum,chat and PM soutions in java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, chat, forum

I want a ready made jsp/java application that contains forums,chat and IM>I want to modify it according to my needs
Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

For a modern web-based Chat(IM) application take a look at [**emite**](http://code.google.com/p/emite/). You also need an XMPP server to deploy it, such as [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/), [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) and [Tigase](http://www.tigase.org/).

For Forum software take a look at the followings:

- [JavaBB](http://www.javabb.org/)
- [Yazd](http://www.forumsoftware.ca/)
- And an Internet forum software comparison is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28other%29)
- With another list of (maybe old) ones [here](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Application/Forum.htm).